# How do i manually load language in settings bundle - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, settings.bundle

In my application, i have implemented some features in settings page. is there any way to change the title strings (NOT THE KEY) of the settings page by fetching the localized title from Database. If it is not possible, is there any way to load the Localized strings file(.lproj) based on the user preference irrespective of device language.

My Scenario:

Case 1:

Implemented:

User Opens the App -> Fetch Localized strings from Server based on device language-> Updating App Strings

To Implement:

Settings Screen -> Should be updated with localized string(device locale) fetched from server.

Case 2:

Implemented:

User Logs in App -> Fetch Localised string from server based on user preference -> Update App Strings

To Implement:

Settings Screen -> Should be updated with localised string(as per the user preferred language)

Other Scenario:
If above two cases "To Implement" is not possible. i need to load the strings (.lproj) in settings bundle manually. for eg. if user logs in and if his/her language is french, i need to load the fr.strings file in settings bundle manually. In this case, when device language is changed, then the settings bundle will load the corresponding language. But in my scenario, i need to load the language in settings bundle of the logged in user irrespective of device language.

In the above scenario, i need to implement "To Implement" section. is there any way to accomplish this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a settings bundle, no, you can't modify it after you've built your app in Xcode. The settings bundle is code signed so it cannot be changed and new strings can't be loaded in. So you can't copy in new strings that have been downloaded from the server.

The settings would have to be moved within your application where you control the source code, and you can swap out the strings as it sounds like you already have for the rest of the application.

Comment: could you elaborate the last point you mentioned. Is it possible to swap out strings in settings screen (in iPhone settings) like i did with in the application

Comment: No, it's not possible. Settings cannot be modified after the app is installed due to code signing (security enforced by Apple.)

The only way to really solve this problem is to move the settings into your application where you control the strings at run time.